# Selecting a Row on page loadup

Tags: html, typescript, onclick, html-helper, p-table

I have a p-table in ngPrime and when I add a row to it, I want that row to be automatically selected. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried looking through the primeNG docs but theres only options for onRowSelect(). I need this row to be selected without a click event on load up.

Also this is an angular application.

Comment: Okay so using ngOnInIt I was able to set the last row in my 'rows' array to be the selected row. Now the selected rows information is popping up in my filter window, but the row itself is not getting highlighted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.